# Is it possible to simplify this condition rewriting using stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring, java-stream, option-type

I have a question about rewriting one chain condition into stream style.

We have an entity with 2 fields:

```
class Test { 
  private boolean isActive = false; 
  private Status status; 

  //getters and setters
}
```

And we have condition:

```
private static boolean isOneAndActiveAndDeprecated(List<Test> test) { 
  return CollectionUtils.size(test) == 1
    && test.get(0).isActive() 
    && Status.DEPRECATED == test.get(0).getStatus(); 
}
```

A list can come null or non-null. So we need to check this.
List size should be one or can come null, not more than one, it's impossible according to business logic before this method.

I'm not sure that it's good implementation. From one side, this condition not so hardly to read but from another side, we have 3 "AND" operators and in my opinion it isn't very clearly here. I guess that it's possible to simplify this method.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the list coming in is always non-null?

Comment: list size should be 1? why do you need stream here?

Comment: @vins brings up a good point - is this going to be used to pass lists with multiple elements and you only want to check when there is 1 element in the list? I think we need more information for the use case before we can give the best answer.

Comment: If `Status` is a enum then you can safely use `==` operator for testing equality. It will much easier and understandable.

Comment: *"I guess that it's possible to simplify this method"* Why do you guess that. There are 4 conditions to be tested, and statement is doing 4 tests. Assuming @Zefick is right, it could be simplified to `test != null && test.size() == 1 && test.get(0).isActive() && test.get(0).getStatus() == Status.DEPRECATED`, but that's not really much of a difference.

Comment: `CollectionUtils.size()` is null safe so this could be slightly simplified to:

 `return CollectionUtils.size(test) == 1 
    && test.get(0).isActive() 
    && Status.DEPRECATED.equals(test.get(0).getStatus());`

Comment: The whole method is questionable, not only its implementation. Why is a method name `isDeprecated` supposed to test for list have a size of *exactly one*? Of course, the method’s name does not give any hint about whether it means `isAnyDeprecated` or `areAllDeprecated`, but it’s solution is even worse than that…

Comment: Besides that, all these utility classes letting `null`s flying under the radar are the *source* of the problem, not the solution. The correct implementation should be `return test.size() == 1 && …`, as a list of size one is not empty in general and best way to handle a `null` list is to throw a `NullPointerException` immediately, which `test.size()` will do.

Comment: Thanks all for response. I updated question according to your questions.

Comment: Add a method to `Test`: `boolean isActiveAndDeprecated() { return active && status==Status.DEPRECATED; }`, then change the other method to `boolean isOneAndActiveAndDeprecated(List<Test> test) { return CollectionUtils.size(test)==1 && test.get(0).isActiveAndDeprecated(); }`

Comment: @Holger, smart solution, thank you))

Answer (score 3):

I have updated your code with Optional class from java 8.

```
     private static boolean isOneAndActiveAndDeprecated(List<Test> test) {
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(test)
                .filter(tests -> test.size() == 1)
                .map(tests -> tests.get(0))
                .filter(Test::isActive)
                .filter(t -> t.getStatus() == Status.DEPRECATED)
                .isPresent();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that’s what we call “simplification” of the original code…

Answer (score 1):

If your `Test` class has an adequate `equals()` method you may try

```
return test.equals(Collections.singletonList(new Test(true, Status.DEPRECATED));
```

Not sure I’d prefer it, though. And sorry, no streams or optionals.